# How to position WPF nested controls absolutely in a window

Tags: wpf, layout, wpf-controls

I have some controls nested in some panels.
The panels themselves are not arranged with the same x position within a window.

I'd like the controls inside the panels to have a fixed position relative to the window, not the panel (so they all line up vertically, in this case).

[image]

To be clear, the Panels themselves have an arbitrary position in the window. One can imagine that the user should be able to effect the Panel positions, but the nested controls would stick to the same X coordinate relative to the window.

I don't think I can use a Canvas, because that's positioning relative to the edges of the canvas.

Any ideas?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `Panel`s... instead, use `Grid`s. If you use `Grid`s, then you can take advantage of the [`Grid.IsSharedSizeScope` Attached Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.grid.issharedsizescope(v=vs.110).aspx) and the [`ColumnDefinition.SharedSizeGroup` Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.definitionbase.sharedsizegroup(v=vs.110).aspx). Using these, you can line up columns from different `Grid`s, as long as you have a parent `Grid` with the `IsSharedSizeScope` property set to true.

Here is an example taken from the first linked page on MSDN:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" DockPanel.Dock="Top">

<Grid ShowGridLines="True" Margin="0,0,10,0">
  <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="FirstColumn"/>
    <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="SecondColumn"/>
  </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
  <Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="FirstRow"/>
  </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Rectangle Fill="Silver" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Width="200" Height="100"/>
    <Rectangle Fill="Blue" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Width="150" Height="100"/>

    <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" FontWeight="Bold">First Column</TextBlock>
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" FontWeight="Bold">Second Column</TextBlock>
</Grid>

<Grid ShowGridLines="True">
  <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="FirstColumn"/>
    <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="SecondColumn"/>
  </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
  <Grid.RowDefinitions>        
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="FirstRow"/>
  </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Rectangle Fill="Silver" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0"/>
    <Rectangle Fill="Blue" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0"/>

    <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" FontWeight="Bold">First Column</TextBlock>
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" FontWeight="Bold">Second Column</TextBlock>
</Grid>

</StackPanel>
```

Comment: Hiya Sheridan! Thanks for the fast answer. I've tried the shared size scope but it still seems to be relative - to the top left corner of the grid (the column size is inherited, not the absolute position within the parent grid). Maybe I did it wrong...

Comment: If your columns line up then of course, the controls in those columns will line up. It works for me anyway.

Comment: That's the problem - the nested controls live inside containers that have arbitrary locations (due to a hierarchical arrangement of the containers). So even if I use shared size groups to hold the controls, I still have to position the grids themselves absolutely within the containers... and I think I'm back to the same problem.